# Why does INSTALLED_APPS in Django settings stops seeing directories if you rename settings.py file?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I work in Pycharm 2019.3.3. So if the settings.py file wasn't renamed, when you start typing a name of a directory inside INSTALLED_APPS, Pycharm indexes what you can choose from. But if you rename the file to something else (common.py eg), it doesn't. But the whole thing works and an app gets included anyway. How can I make it index properly?
Same thing happens if you put the settings.py file inside a project/project/settings/ directory (instead of the default project/project). What actions should be taken to make it work as intended?

Comment: To clarify, I managed to run the app with $set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.project.common command

Comment: Using Django 3.2.4

Comment: Is there a Djagno support pane where you can tell it where to look? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/django-support.html#dee9ea9b. Don't use PyCharm myself but it sounds like something you can config